# Copying file and saving with different file name

Tags: android, file, directory, file-copying

I am trying to copy file in android.I have the filepath of the file.I want to copy it to another folder with different file name.I am using below code but it doesn't work.My file is video file.
   I get error-

```
/storage/emulated/0/testcopy.mp4: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Below is my code

```
 File source=new File(filepath);
    File destination=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/testcopy.mp4");
    copyFile(source.getAbsolutePath(),destination.getAbsolutePath());



private void copyFile(String inputPath, String outputPath) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {

            //create output directory if it doesn't exist
            File dir = new File (outputPath);
            if (!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }


            in = new FileInputStream(inputPath );
            out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;

            // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;

        }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
            Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a directory with name "/storage/emulated/0/testcopy.mp4" here

```
//create output directory if it doesn't exist
File dir = new File (outputPath);
if (!dir.exists())
{
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

try this code

```
//create output directory if it doesn't exist
File dir = (new File (outputPath)).getParentFile();
if (!dir.exists())
{
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Them main problem is that you are trying to write the file that is a directory. To avoid this exception, create the directory first, then write the file:

```
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    // creating a new folder if doesn't exist
    boolean success = folder.exists() || folder.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(folder, "filename.mp4");

    try {
        if (!file.exists() && success) file.createNewFile();
        ...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        ...
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```